# App Store iOS binary rejected: Your app includes non-iOS device images in the app

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore, mac-appstore, app-store-connect

Recently our iOS app got rejected by App Store review team stating **your app includes non-iOS device images in the app** along with following screenshot.

[image]

Mobile phones are an important category in our app and we can not remove related data. What is the solution on this?

Comment: I think it may be referring to the Android OS screenshot inside the phone, if I were you, I'd try using the phone screenshots with just a normal background, and not with a screenshot of android as the photo inside the phone - if that makes sense? Try all phones to have the same background as the first phone does in the picute.

Answer (score 1):

Consider removing references (links, images) to other platforms in the text, screenshots from your app to make it past the review process.

You may find this discussion helpful:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688956/3-1-details-we-noticed-that-your-app-contains-irrelevant-platform-information-r

The screenshots would get displayed on the App Store page for the app on Web and App Store app, and Apple doesn't allow reference to other platforms as part of the app metadata.

It appears you are in violation of the following App Store review guideline:

- https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#performance

> **2.3.10** Make sure your app is focused on the iOS, Mac, Apple TV or Apple Watch experience, and don’t include names, icons, or imagery of other mobile platforms in your app or metadata, unless there is specific, approved interactive functionality. Make sure your app metadata is focused on the app itself and its experience. Don’t include irrelevant information, including but not limited to information about Apple or the development process.